# Create a two-way table crossing the levels of a factor, with ids in another column

Tags: r

with such a matrix (or dataframe)

```
 a<-matrix(c(1,2,3,1,4,2,5,"A","A","B","B","A","B","A"),nrow=7,ncol=2)
```

Considering I have ids in the first column, and levels of a factor in the second one.
How could I obtain a two-ways table of co-occurences of the levels ?

Expected output :

```
    A    B
A   4    2
B   2    3
```

Thank you,

edit : found the answer... this is soooo dumb :

```
crossprod(table(a[,1],a[,2]))
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?.  Perhaps `table(as.data.frame(a))`

Comment: probably `table(a[,1],a[,2])`

Comment: expected output (co-occurences) is a 2x2 symetric table with "A" and "B" as both rows and columns with diagonal 4 (nb of A) and 3 (nb of B) and in other cells the number of ids having both A and B lines : (Sorry I don't know how to draw tables in stack comments)

I.e. 2 Because there are two ids (1 and 2) sharing both "A" and "B" values
Of course my goal is to use it for more than two levels in the second column.

Comment: Please update your post with expected output based on the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better late than never, I just edited the op and forgot to answer, Here is the solution I figured out :

```
crossprod(table(a[,1],a[,2]))
```